# Why doesn't Lightning Web Component lookup field working properly on mobile browsers?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

For some reason a lookup field in a Lightning Web Component is not working properly when accessed from a mobile browser. Not working properly means that the autocomplete function does not work properly. This works fine when accessing the community page on a desktop, but not a mobile.

This is a Lightning Web Component with the field below being a lookup to the Contact object within a lightning-record-edit-form compenent

```
<lightning-input-field field-name="Related_Contact__c"></lightning-input-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently lookup type fields are not supported by this component in Mobile...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation

The solution is custom component as per the example:
https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup-lwc

Answer (score 0):

This is [now supported](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/documentation) for the mobile app:

> The lookup type is supported in Experience Builder sites, Lightning
> Experience, and the Salesforce mobile app